# title art in url

Tags: url, title

i have news "Show me your project" and url = http://site.com/show.php?id=4
how can i create url = http://site.com/show-me-your-project?

thanks

Comment: Just like you did. What problems are you having with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look up URL reWriting with .htaccess (which is what i assume you need) or any other url Rewriting implementations

Comment: please give me simple example :)